# 12 Sided Polygon in a Square

Tags: geometry

(Thanks Semiclassical and Andrei for pointing out errors in my question)

I don't really know if this asked already, but my question is - Take a 12-sided regular polygon that fits in a square of 2048cm. What would be the length of **a side** of the polygon inside it?

As for orientation, ***8*** of the vertices of the **duodecagon** must lie on the perimeter of the square

Comment: If you can't find for n sides, then find for 12 - I just wanted to know the answer for a project of mine.

Comment: Obviously your figure is wrong. The hexagon will fit inside a rectangle. If the length of the side of the hexagon is $l$, the height of the rectangle is $2l$ and the width is $l\sqrt 3$

Comment: One complication to this is that the size might depend on how the polygon is oriented, e.g., if one side is parallel to the square or not. But even if that’s true (which it may not be) one should presumably pick whichever orientation needs the smallest square.

Comment: And in many cases you can't have **all** the vertices on the perimeter of the square. Some will be in the interior

Comment: oh ok...
ok since its a 12 sided polygon, i want it so that 8 of the 12 vertices lie on the perimeter and its a regular 12 sided polygon i can visualise that much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is well-known that every regular polygon has an inscribed circle (incircle), that is, a circle that touches all of the polygon's sides.  Consider the inscribed circle of the 12-sided polygon. Now each of the four sides of the square has a side of the 12-sided polygon that is on the same line as the side of the square, so the inscribed circle must touch those four lines.  Three different tangent lines uniquely determine a circle, so this circle must be the same as the inscribed circle of the square.

Now if you have a regular polygon with $ n $ sides of length $ a $ each, and the radius of the inscribed circle is $ ρ $, then $ a = 2ρ \tan(π/n) $.  To see this, consider the right triangle whose vertexes are the center of the circle, a vertex of the polygon, and the midpoint of a side adjacent to it.  The angle of this triangle at the center is $ π/n$, the leg adjacent to this is $ρ$,  and the other leg is $ a/2 $.

Now consider the previous identity for both the square and the 12-sided polygon.  Let's call the side of the square $ a_4 $ and the side of the 12-sided polygon $ a_{12} $.  For the square we simply get $ a_4 = 2ρ $; for the 12-sided polygon we get $ a_{12} = 2ρ\tan(π/12) = a_4\tan(π/12) $.

I won't try to derive the exact value $ \tan(π/12) = 2 - \sqrt3 $ here, because I assume you only need an approximate value here.  That's easy to compute or look up from a table: $ \tan(π/12) = 0.2679 $.  You gave $ a_4 = 2048\,\mathrm{cm} $, so multiplying those we get $ a_{12} = 548.7\,\mathrm{cm} $.

Comment: Thanks so much!